# Adding an element to array without an array list

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment with simple CRUD operations and I'm stuck. We are not supposed to use ArrayList in this one.
The program should allow user to add a new Car into an array, and the information should contain car id, brand, year of release and the price.

So far, I am not sure about the following:

How to add a new item containing all the information entered by the user into already existing array?

I can't unfortunately specify what is wrong with the code since it just won't execute at all.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    public class Car_main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int cont = 0;
    String cBrand, cId, cYear, searchBrand, searchYear, removeId, updateId;
    String  cPrice;
    Car carArr[] = new Car[0];
    int counter = 0;

    int choice;
    Scanner scanObj = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (cont == 0) {
        System.out.println("Fill in: \n1 Add a new car\n2 "

                + "if you want to change car ID\n3 "

                + "if you want to remove car ID \n4 "

                + "if you want to search by the brand\n5 "

                + "if you want to search by the year of release \n6 "

                + "calculate the total sum \n7"

                + "show the list");

        choice = scanObj.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
    case 1: 
            System.out.println("Your choice is 1. Add a new car. Fill in car id, car brand, release year and price);");
            cId= scanObj.next();
            cBrand = scanObj.next();
            cYear = scanObj.next();
            cPrice = scanObj.next();


            Car c_obj = new Car (cId, cBrand, cYear, cPrice);
            counter++;
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you have posted code on here without specifying what is wrong with it.  We expect to see what you expect the code to do, why you expect it to do this, what it is actually doing, and why it is wrong.  Please [edit] your question to include this information, and then I will consider retracting my downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thanks for your comment, I have edited the question

Comment: *I can't unfortunately specify what is wrong with the code since it just won't execute at all.* Surely you must be getting an error message then?  That counts as "what is wrong" in my books.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Java have a fixed size. So you either have to create an array with a sufficient size or you have to instantiate a new array every time you add a new element and copy the existing values to the new array.

Comment: thanks! i wonder if I can write 0 if I don't know the exact size of the array? like here:   Car carArr[] = new Car[0];

Comment: Technically you can do this, but there is no point in creating an empty array.